# How to open Android application automatically when any one of particular port sms receiving?

Tags: java, android, cordova, sms

I am new for android, I have done one android application using phonegap, but in this application I am going to implement a new concept. That is nothing but this application want to open automatically when an sms receiving with particular port. 
So how to implement this concept? Actually after login the app form that username sent to backend and reply via the same port. If entered username is correct, the reply message is true otherwise false will return.

In our apps when receiving that particular message take the response and check if it is true, redirect to the home form else displaying the login form again with error message. This is the concept.

Now my Activity class is as follows, but I don't know how to change my activity class for getting this concept.

So any body help me how to implements this concept...thanks in advance.

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import org.apache.cordova.*;
 import android.view.Menu;

 public class SMSActivity extends DroidGap
 {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sms);
        //super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.logo);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_sms, menu);
        return true;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)  for SMS_RECEIVED. Please refer this tutorial this may help you.

1) [SMS messaging](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android)
2) [React on incoming message](http://www.anddev.org/recognize-react_on_incoming_sms-t295.html)

Comment: Hai,thanks for your help, its working fine, but i want to redirect to html home page from the SMSReciever class file if that recieved sms is true.if it is false display the login page with error message which is invalid login. how to get it?

Comment: you can set the boolean value as true if message is received and else set it to false,and then redirect your page according to this boolean values.

Comment: ok, but i want the redirection code properly, canu send me please?

Comment: when the message was received my application throws the error which is your application unexpectedly stopped.what is the issue?